# Multiple sub-hashes out of one hash

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a hash:

```
hash = {"a_1_a" => "1", "a_1_b" => "2", "a_1_c" => "3", "a_2_a" => "3",
        "a_2_b" => "4", "a_2_c" => "4"}
```

What's the best way to get the following sub-hashes:

```
[{"a_1_a" => "1", "a_1_b" => "2", "a_1_c" => "3"},
 {"a_2_a" => "3", "a_2_b" => "4", "a_2_c" => "4"}]
```

I want them grouped by the key, based on the regexp `/^a_(\d+)/`.  I'll have 50+ key/value pairs in the original hash, so something dynamic would work best, if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Such a quick selection of the first answer offered may discourage other answers and short-circuit those still working on answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before selecting an answer, some wait much longer than that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I'm new here :)

Comment: In fact, some wait for months! Others never do! LOL

Comment: @A.D. this question was flagged as too broad: as it stands, this question is indeed too broad: "the best way" can mean "smallest code", "fastest code", "most readable code", etc. Please be more specify in what your question is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're only concerned about the middle component you can use `group_by` to get you most of the way there:

```
hash.group_by do |k,v|
  k.split('_')[1]
end.values.map do |list|
  Hash[list]
end

# => [{"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2", "a_1_c"=>"3"}, {"a_2_a"=>"3", "a_2_b"=>"4", "a_2_c"=>"4"}]
```

The final step is extracting the grouped lists and combining those back into the required hashes.

Comment: This looks like what OP is looking for. Can also make it a bit more terse if OP is interested in that kind of thing
`hash.group_by { |k, _| k.split('_')[1] }.values.map(&:to_h)`

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

```
def partition_hash(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), h|
    key = k[/(?<=_).+(?=_)/]
    h[key] = (h[key] || {}).merge(k=>v)
  end.values
end
```

**Example**

```
hash = {"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2", "a_1_c"=>"3", "a_2_a"=>"3", "a_2_b"=>"4", "a_2_c"=>"4"}
partition_hash(hash)
  #=> [{"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2", "a_1_c"=>"3"},
  #    {"a_2_a"=>"3", "a_2_b"=>"4", "a_2_c"=>"4"}]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
enum = hash.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2", "a_1_c"=>"3", "a_2_a"=>"3",
  #                  "a_2_b"=>"4", "a_2_c"=>"4"}:each_with_object({})>
```

The first element of this enumerator is generated and passed to the block, and the block variables are computed using *parallel assignment*.

```
(k,v), h = enum.next
  #=> [["a_1_a", "1"], {}] 
k #=> "a_1_a" 
v #=> "1" 
h #=> {}
```

and the block calculation is performed.

```
key = k[/(?<=_).+(?=_)/]
  #=> "1" 
h[key] = (h[key] || {}).merge(k=>v)
  #=> h["1"] = (h["1"] || {}).merge("a_1_a"=>"1")
  #=> h["1"] = (nil || {}).merge("a_1_a"=>"1")
  #=> h["1"] = {}.merge("a_1_a"=>"1")
  #=> h["1"] = {"a_1_a"=>"1"}
```

so now

```
h #=> {"1"=>{"a_1_a"=>"1"}}
```

The next value of `enum` is now generated and passed to the block, and the following calculations are performed.

```
(k,v), h = enum.next
  #=> [["a_1_b", "2"], {"1"=>{"a_1_a"=>"1"}}] 
k #=> "a_1_b" 
v #=> "2" 
h #=> {"1"=>{"a_1_a"=>"1"}} 

key = k[/(?<=_).+(?=_)/]
  #=> "1" 
h[key] = (h[key] || {}).merge(k=>v)
  #=> h["1"] = (h["1"] || {}).merge("a_1_b"=>"2")
  #=> h["1"] = ({"a_1_a"=>"1"}} || {}).merge("a_1_b"=>"2")
  #=> h["1"] = {"a_1_a"=>"1"}}.merge("a_1_b"=>"2")
  #=> h["1"] = {"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2"}
```

After the remaining four elements of `enum` have been passed to the block the following has is returned.

```
h #=> {"1"=>{"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2", "a_1_c"=>"3"},
  #    "2"=>{"a_2_a"=>"3", "a_2_b"=>"4", "a_2_c"=>"4"}}
```

The final step is simply to extract the values.

```
h.values
  #=> [{"a_1_a"=>"1", "a_1_b"=>"2", "a_1_c"=>"3"},
  #    {"a_2_a"=>"3", "a_2_b"=>"4", "a_2_c"=>"4"}]
```